# How to assign data from different groups to different variables with a SQL query?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

I want to assign different groups of query result to different variables by executing just one `select` statement. For example:

```
res_a, res_b, res_c = select * from table where name in ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How can I do this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the provided statement in DolphinDB, the logic is to access the table by row and assign each row to a variable. The result will be returned in a dictionary. You can refer to the following script:

```
t  = table(['a', 'b', 'c'] as sym, [1, 2, 3] as val)
res_a, res_b, res_c = select * from t where sym in ['a', 'b', 'c']
res_a

// output
val->1
sym->'a'
```

To assign results of the group “name=`a`" to the corresponding variable `res_a`, results of the group “name=`b`" to variable `res_b`…, you can try the following script:

```
t = table(`a`c`b`a`b`c as sym, 1 2 3 4 5 6 as value)
def mysql_test(col): select * from t where sym in col
res_a, res_b, res_c=each(mysql_test, [`a,`b,`c])
```

The method adopts the function `each` to loop through all elements in the column `sym`, so that you can query the three groups of data separately. Then, the results from the different groups can be assigned to the corresponding variables.